# How do I add an RFC4370 Proxied Authorization Control to a JNDI LDAP request?

Tags: java, ldap, jndi

I have an existing JNDI based application where I need to add an RFC4370 Proxied Authorization Control to the LDAP reconnect() method in order to proxy the authorization to the LDAP server (OID 2.16.840.1.113730.3.4.18).

Weirdly, RFC4370 support seems to be missing from the set of controls available in the java.naming.ldap package tree, so it looks like I will need to add an implementation of this control myself.

I am stuck on the generation of the ASN.1 encoding for the control. Looking at the JDK source, the controls are using JDK dependent code to render the ASN.1 (com.sun.jndi.ldap.BerEncoder).

I need to avoid adding large dependencies (but could add an ASN.1 library if it was required), cannot depend on JDK specific internals, and I am not in a position to rewrite this code to use a different LDAP API.

Does anyone have a recommended solution for this?

Comment: Perhaps this could help:https://docs.ldap.com/ldap-sdk/docs/javadoc/com/unboundid/ldap/sdk/controls/ProxiedAuthorizationV1RequestControl.html and the source: https://docs.ldap.com/ldap-sdk/docs/javadoc/src-html/com/unboundid/ldap/sdk/controls/ProxiedAuthorizationV1RequestControl.html#line.149

Comment: Like the JDK itself, the unbound SDK uses an internal ASN.1 implementation so I have the same problem. As pointed out, I am not in a position to rewrite the code to use a different LDAP API.